# facebook app authorizing: An error occurred. Please try again later

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I’ve just created a Facebook app, this is my first attempt and I followed Facebook developer’s documentation totally, while completing everything as stated I am stucked at this error while authorizing app:

***An error occurred. Please try again later.***

```
    <?php
    $app_id = '1603369454518730';
    $app_secret = '511b194f6sdgg6eca7cc748d7be6d82d';
    //$canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp";
    $canvas_page = "http://myappweb.com/app/landhere.php";
    $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri= " . urlencode($canvas_page);

    //Requesting Signed Parameter:
    $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

    //User Info. Variables:
    try {
        $userId = $data["user_id"];

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e -> getMessage();
        echo "<br>";
    }

    if (!empty($data["user_id"])) {
        if ($data['page']['liked']) {
            echo "hello";
        } else {
            echo "like page";
        }
    } else {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
    }
    ?>
```

Ive tried suggestion that I found in other threads such as checking *app id* and *app secret*, *disabling sandbox*. But none of this has worked yet for me. Kindly help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into coding too much, but kinda sorted it out.
Your canvas page should be the url of the page not your app url.
Also I tried using the following code and it works.

```
<?php 

     $app_id = "APP_ID";

     $canvas_page = "CANVAS_PAGE";

     $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
            echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
     } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Ive updated the code as you suggested but the problem still persists. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, (My interaction with the PHP SDK is minimal), you need to add a redirection url to which FB will return when authentication is complete, to acomplish that you will have to do two steps:

1)    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

2)  In you'r applications' page: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/app_id
press Edit and in "Select how your app integrates with Facebook"
select Website.

put in the URL the you'r http://apps.facebook.com/myapp.

good luck

Comment: can you just guide me a lil what should be the `$canvas_page/redirect_uri`. address of of my app over facebook i.e. _http://apps.facebook.com/myapp_ or the page at the my website that contains above code _http://myappweb.com/app/landhere.php_